# In "This is an adventure to me", what is the function of "to me"?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, syntax

> This is an adventure to me

In this sentence, "an adventure to me" is the subject complement.
I'd like to know the function of "to me". Is it a post modifier of "adventure"? Or is it a prep. object? (which seems improbable since the verb in the sentence is intransitive)

Comment: _To me_ is a prepositional phrase. _Me_ is its object. It seems unlikely that _an adventure to me_ is a constituent, and therefore can't be a subject complement, because _to me_ can be moved without changing meaning: _To me, this is an adventure_. The noun phrase _an adventure_ is the predicate noun; _to me_ is basically functioning as an adverbial.

Comment: @JohnLawler. Could you please expound on the relationship of position-in-sentence to role?  It's tricky for me.  Also, a quick-and-dirty definition of **constituent** would be great.  Is a consitutent subject, verb, object?

Answer (score 2):

The object of this sentence is *an adventure*. The subject is *this*. *To me* is a prepositional phrase with *me* as its object, and it relates to the verb *to be*. To illustrate, it might be re-written:

> To me, this is an adventure.

It means that the speaker considers *this* (whatever that might be) an adventure, but recognises that others may not.

Comment: Illustration is unclear. Recommended action is replace it with "This is to me an adventure." to emphasize the relationship to the verb by moving it closer and follow the verb instead of preceding it.

Comment: Also recommend using "is" instead of "to be" to conform with the initial conjugation.